# Convert Sequelize Query to BigQuery Query

Tags: sql, node.js, google-bigquery, sequelize.js

Hello I need to convert this Sequelize Query to bigQuery sql Query syntax.

```
Comment.findAll({ where: {artifact_id: id, parent_id: null},
        include: [
            { model: db.User, attributes: ['id','first_name', 'last_name'] },
            { model: db.artifact, attributes: ['id','original_artifact_name'] },
            { model: db.status, attributes: ['id','status_name'] },
            { model: Comment, as: 'replies', include: [{ model: db.User, attributes: ['id','first_name', 'last_name'] }] }
        ]
    })
```

Can any one help with this ?
When I do left join of any table like this

```
SELECT a.*, b.group_name as parent_grp_name, c.org_name as parent_org_name
     FROM ${DB}.groups a LEFT JOIN ${DB}.groups b ON b.id = a.parent_group_id
     LEFT JOIN ${DB}.organizations c ON c.id = a.organization_id
     ORDER BY a.created_at
     LIMIT ${limit}
     OFFSET ${offset}`
```

it gives me record as a single object with both tables data in it. I want to get joined table data as seperate object.

Comment: Could you please show an example of data you have and an example of what it should look like in the end.

Comment: I need this type of data as query result
 "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "UserId": 1,
            "artifactId": 13,
            "statusId": 1,
            "User": {
                "id": 1,
                "first_name": "faiza",
                "last_name": "zahoor"
            },
            "artifact": {
                "id": 13,
                "original_artifact_name": "childrens-clothers-designer.jpg"
            },
 "status": {
                "id": 1,
                "status_name": "uploaded"
 },
 "Replies": [array of joined table objects]}]

Comment: Please add model definitions and associations

Comment: actually I am querying data from gcloud bigQuery dataset so associations are same as in above sequelize query